# How do I get Vim to highlight matching <>?

Tags: vim

For syntax highlight and press key "%", vi only support "()" and "{}" by default.

Is there any plugin which can support "<>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in option `matchpairs` for this by adding the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
set matchpairs+=<:>
```

That will add the pair of `<` and `>`.